# How Put the control in memory at run time and paste it on the form at design time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created this class:

```
Friend Class mybutton

    Public Property Location As Point
    Public Property Size As Size
    Public Property BackColor As Color
    Public Property Text As String

    ' some serializers require a simple ctor
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    ' create object from passed PB
    Public Sub New(pb As Button)
        Location = pb.Location
        Size = pb.Size
        BackColor = pb.BackColor
        Text = pb.Text
    End Sub

End Class
```

And in the button event

```
  ' Create a button at runtime
    Dim button As New mybutton
    button.Text = "Click Me"
    button.Location = New Point(50, 50)

    ' Serialize the button object to a memory stream
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
    formatter.Serialize(stream, button)
    ' stream.Position = 0
    ' Set the memory stream as a custom clipboard format
    Dim dataObject As New DataObject()
    dataObject.SetData("MyButton", stream)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject)
```

Then I ran the program, clicked on the button, closed the program, and tried to paste the result on the form, but I didn't find anything

**What should it be**

Comment: I don't see where you're creating a `Button`  object to pass to the `myButton` constructor, and even if you were, that object isn't actually saved. I also don't see where the data would be coming from to put in the clipboard; it just looks like an empty stream. Are we missing some stuff?

Comment: Hello Michael , I am creating the button in the button click event, with Text "ClickMe" And  Location 50,50 , Please see the code again

Comment: Yes, I see that. I don't know how the `BinaryFormatter` is going to interpret an object, but I also can't see what you want in the clipboard. Do you actually want what you would get if you selected a control during design and copied THAT to the clipboard?

Comment: @MichaelFoster Can you help me put a button in clipboard when the program is running and then I can paste it on the form

Comment: @MichaelFoster Re how the binary formatter will interpret an object, it is designed to write a .NET object in a way that it will be reconstituted in the deserialization.  There seems to be an assumption here that the designer is expecting exactly this clipboard data.

Comment: Your class is not even close to a Button Control and in any case cannot be used to serialize / deserialize a Control as VS does. You need `System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomComponentSerializationService` that can handle a `CodeDomSerializationStore`, with all references to the assemblies and Resources used by the object (if you want to serialize Controls classes that are not marked as `[Serializable]`, plus preserving state)

Comment: When you copy a control in Visual Studio, such as a button or dataset, you will be able to make a copy of it by simply choosing the Paste command, which means that the clipboard contains information from it.
This means that the same thing can be done with the code.
Side question on the same topic: Is it possible to view the clipboard content when copying a control in the Visual Studio development environment?